# Error in QuickSort using median rule

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort

Im solving the QuickSort assignment at Algorithms class by Stanford and using the median rule to select the pivot element. The input is numbers from 1-10000 and output is the number of comparisons

My function are as follows :

```
public static  int noOfComp = 0;
public static void quick_sort(int[] a, int p, int r){
    if(p<r) {
        noOfComp+= r-p;
        int mid = partition(a, p, r);
        quick_sort(a, p, mid-1); 
        quick_sort(a, mid+1, r);
    }
}

public static int median(int a[],int p, int r){
    int firstPos = p;
    int len = r-p+1;
    int lastPos = r;
    int midPos = len%2==0 ? p + (len)/2-1: p + (len)/2 ;
    int first  = a[firstPos];
    int middle = a[midPos];
    int last   = a[lastPos];

    if (first <= middle) {
      if (middle <= last) {
          // first - middle - last
          return midPos;
      } else if (first <= last) {
          // first - last - middle
          return lastPos;
      }
      // last - first - middle
      return firstPos;
    }

    if (first <= last) {
        // middle - first - last
        return firstPos;
    } else if (middle <= last) {
        // middle - last - first
        return lastPos;
    }
    // last - middle - first
    return midPos;
}


public static int partition(int[] a, int p, int r){
    int chosen = median(a,p,r);
    swap(a, p, chosen);
    int pivot = a[p];
    int i = p;
    for (int j = p+1; j < a.length; j++) {
        if (a[j] < pivot) {
            i++;
            swap(a, i, j);
        }
    }

    swap(a, i,p);
    return i;
}

//main
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable{

    int i=0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Uzumaki Naruto\\Documents\\QuickSort.txt"));
    while(in.hasNext()){
        i++;
        in.next();
    }
    int[] a = new int[i];
    i=0;
    Scanner in2 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Uzumaki Naruto\\Documents\\QuickSort.txt"));
    while(in2.hasNext()){
        a[i++] = in2.nextInt();
    }
    quick_sort(a, 0, a.length-1);        
    System.out.println("Number of comparisons : " + noOfComp);
}
```

The answer to question seems to be around 128k , but my algorithm output it 132k. I've read the code number of times but unable to ascertain the error.

Comment: My suggestion is that difference in results is due to equal numbers. In some realizations array is divided into three parts: <pivot, =pivot, >pivot. In your realization the parts are: <pivot, pivot(one element), >=pivot.

Comment: @OlegPestov Thanks, but the problem statement mentions that there are only unique numbers int the array

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, I also get an average count of around 132k with your code, executed on randomly shuffled arrays of unique numbers. I did not find any mistake in the algorithm, except for the following one, but it's not influencing your count result, which assumed correct code:

The loop in *partition* has a bad exit condition:

```
for (int j = p+1; j < a.length; j++) {
```

It should be:

```
for (int j = p+1; j <= r; j++) {
```

The following is not an error, but you can rewrite

```
int len = r-p+1;
int midPos = len%2==0 ? p + (len)/2-1: p + (len)/2 ;
```

as:

```
int midPos = p + (r-p)/2;
```

**But:** You did not count the comparisons made in the function *median*, and this should normally be done, otherwise an algorithm cannot be fairly compared with another (variant). So that results in 2 or 3 more comparisons per call of *partition*. This increases the average count to around 148k!

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot) it says that:

> the expected number of comparisons needed to sort *n* elements with random pivot selection is 1.386 *n.log(n)*. **Median-of-three pivoting** brings this down to ≈ 1.188 *n.log(n)*.

The thing is that for *n* = 10 000, 1.188 *n.log(n)* ≈ 158k so your algorithm seems to do fewer comparisons than this estimate, at least for this particular case of *n*.

I do see a way to reduce that number again.

## Reducing the number of comparisons

The main idea is to profit from the comparisons you make in the function *median* by already putting the lowest and highest of the three inspected values in the right partition, so they do not need to be treated further by the loop in the function *partition*.

To give an example, if you have an array like this:

```
5, 1, 2, 9, 3
```

Then *median* will compare 5, 2 and 3 and choose 3 as pivot value. The function could now be extended to also put the three investigated elements in the right order, without extra comparisons, to get this:

```
2, 1, 3*, 9, 5
```

And then the pivot element would not have to be swapped to the start of the array, but to the second slot, because we already have decided that the left most element belongs to the lower partition:

```
2, 3*, 1, 0, 5
```

And now the main partition loop can concentrate on this sub-array, because also the last element is known the belong to the upper partition:

```
2, 3*, [1, 0], 5
```

At the end of the loop the final swap will be with the second element instead of the first:

```
2, 0, 1, 3*, 5
```

This will reduce the number of comparisons in the main loop with 2.

In this variant, the *median* function will always return the index of the second slot, after making a few swaps in the array:

```
public static int median(int a[],int p, int r){
    int m = p + (r-p)/2;

    // actually sort the three elements:
    noOfComp++;
    if (a[r] < a[m]) {
        swap(a, r, m);
    }
    if (p < m) { // more than 2 elements
        noOfComp++;
        if (a[m] < a[p]) {
            swap(a, m, p);
            noOfComp++;
            if (a[r] < a[m]) {
                swap(a, r, m);
            }
        }
        // put the middle element (pivot) in second slot
        swap(a, m, p+1);
    }
    return p+1;
}
```

And *partition* will look like this:

```
public static int partition(int[] a, int p, int r){
    int k = median(a, p, r); // always returns p+1 as pivot's index
    int i = k; // (k..i] is lower partition
    for (int j = p+2; j < r; j++) { // positions p and r can be excluded
        if (a[j] < a[k]) {
            i++;
            swap(a, i, j);
        }
    }
    swap(a, i, k); // place pivot between partitions
    return i;
}
```

In *quick_sort* the count of comparisons will be two less:

```
    noOfComp += r-p-2;
```

With the above adjustments the number of comparisons goes down from 148k to 135k on average.

So I am afraid that although the *actual* number of comparisons has been reduced this way, it still does not match the 128k.

## Other ideas

I tried using [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) when the array became small, but it did not yield much of an improvement. Another idea is to improve the search for the median by looking at more elements, but only if the array is not too small, as the cost of looking for one must be small compared to the partitioning effort.

But the assignment may not allow for all this tweaking.